# Jquery only prepend if object dosen't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>some content</span>
</div>
```

I want to prepend this with some content

```
$( "#wrapper" ).prepend( "<img class='img' src=''>" );
```

however I don't want it to prepend if the img is already there.

I can't do something like checking how long the wrapper div is because it's content comes from a database and is of variable length.

Comment: `if (!$('.fourfifth').prev('img')) { $( ".fourfifth" ).prepend( "<img class='img' src=''>" ); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like

```
if( $( ".fourfifth" ).prev("img.img").length == 0) {
  $( ".fourfifth" ).prepend( "<img class='img' src=''>" );
}
```